# How can you rename a wiki page in Fossil SCM?

Tags: fossil

How can I rename a wiki page in Fossil SCM?

In my particular case, I'd like to rename my project (in Admin, Configuration, Project Name), but if I do that  then when I click Home in the main menu nothing is displayed, because there's not yet a wiki page whose name matches my new Project Name.  I'd like to rename my project, and rename my (sole) wiki page to match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can’t rename a wiki page, because wiki pages are identified by their name; that would be tantamount to deleting the old page. And you can’t delete a wiki page; Fossil never deletes an existing artifact.

But you *can* create a *new* wiki page (with your project's new name), and copy the old page's contents to the new one. If you remove all the text from the old wiki page, that old page will disappear from the list of wiki pages.

There's something to be said for a `wiki rename` command that would implement this sequence of actions automatically, but that hasn't been done so far.  You can post a request on the [fossil forum](https://fossil-scm.org/forum/forum), and see if one of the developers picks it up. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In principle it can be renamed by running the following in a SQLite file editor (if you try it from the "Raw SQL Commands" page, only the first UPDATE is successful):

```
UPDATE attachment SET target='new name' WHERE target='old name';
UPDATE event SET comment=':new name' WHERE comment=':old name';
UPDATE event SET comment='+new name' WHERE comment='+old name';
UPDATE event SET comment=replace(comment, '[old name]', '[new name]') WHERE comment like '%[old name]%';
UPDATE tag SET tagname='wiki-new name' WHERE tagname='wiki-old name';
```

At first glance it works but then you will not be able to update the content (which in fact can be useful to protect an article).

For the renaming to be effective you also have to modify the binary blob that contains the article, as well as update the deltas in case you have made previous edits.

I was working on [this script](https://github.com/aaferrari/fossil-editor) that does the above automatically. To use it you have to execute the following in a console:

```
fossil_editor.py oldname newname repo.fossil
```

If everything goes well, something like this should appear:

```
This is fossil version 2.16 [7aedd56758] 2021-07-02 12:46:01 UTC
Artifact 61e7cc32f7 updated to 84b8195fe6
Artifact c2290869ad updated to 3ff4f96773
Artifact e993cd0331 updated to bc7e8d52df
References updated
```